# Split 1 email column to 2 column in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have these records:

```
Name         mail
------------------
George        a
George        m
Paul          b
Lisa          c
Lisa          n
Sara          d
```

I want a consolidated list like this:

```
Name        mail1      mail2
------------------------------
George          a          m
Paul            b          -
Lisa            c          n
Sara            d          -
```

How could I do that?

Comment: Look up Pivot. This has been answered thousands of times.

Answer (score 1):

You can use row_number to generate numbers to the rows and then pivot using it, something like this:

```
select * from
(
  select *, 
    row_number() over (partition by Name order by mail) as RN
  from yourtable
) S
pivot (
  max(mail) for RN in ([1],[2])
) p
```